# How to catch an exception that was already caught by a nested function call in Python

Tags: python, error-handling

In the following example I would like to be able to call the function `b()` from `a()`, and for `a()` to recognize that an `IndexError` has occurred in `b()`.

```
def a():
    try:
        b()
    except IndexError:
        print('Caught the error in a!')

def b():
    array = ["First", "Second"]

    try:
        print(array[2])
    except IndexError:
        print('Caught the error in b!')

a()
```

The output of this script looks like this:

```
Caught the error in b!
```

What I would like to see is a way for this script to output the following:

```
Caught the error in b!
Caught the error in a!
```

I would greatly prefer an answer with the constraint that modifications only be made to the function `a()` for the specific real-world scenario I'm actually dealing with, but will accept another answer if this isn't possible.

My (incorrect) intuition would assume that the script is simply terminating after the exception is being caught in `b()`, but the following example proves that this is not the case:

```
def a():
    try:
        b()
    except IndexError:
        print('Caught the error in a!')
    print('Both chances are over now.')

def b():
    array = ["First", "Second"]

    try:
        print(array[2])
    except IndexError:
        print('Caught the error in b!')

a()
```

This script will output the following:

```
Caught the error in b!
Both chances are over now.
```

Which proves to me that the function `a()` will continue executing after the `IndexError` exception occurs in `b()`.

Comment: If you catch the exception in `b`, then it won't be propagated out of it. If you don't catch it, then it will be propagated out. It is very simple, just use the mechanism the way it is meant, don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: In the real-world problem I'm trying to solve it would be best if I didn't modify the called function (`b()` in the minimum reproducible example I've given). I just wanted to see if it was possible to detect the exception in `a()` given the constraint that it has already been caught in `b()`. The answers so far have already provided a very lightweight solution that does modify `b()` and will be sufficient if there isn't a way to solve this problem by only modifying `a()`.

Comment: The interface of a function cannot by modified from the outside. The interface of this function is that it does not throw an exception. When using it, you should not even care what happened inside. You called the function, it did something, it turned a result, whatever happened inside is not your business (as the caller of the function). If information about the exception is needed outside, then the function's interface is not ok and you have to modify it or write a new function.

Comment: @zvone I like that explanation much better. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
def a():
    try:
        b()
    except IndexError:
        print('Caught the error in a!')
    print('Both chances are over now.')

def b():
    array = ["First", "Second"]

    try:
        print(array[2])
    except IndexError:
        print('Caught the error in b!')
        raise

a()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I attempted solving this problem with the raise keyword before posting this question and had trouble. When you run the given script with the raise keyword added where you've suggested, what is your output?

Comment: Sorry, had the functions backward. Put the raise in b. I will edit.

Comment: I was using the keyword `raise` incorrectly. If there isn't a way to solve this problem by only modifying `a()` then this solution will be lightweight enough to serve my needs.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to see that the exception occurred from the calling function, so some modification is necessary. I like the use of raise (which is basically re-raise the exception), although returning a value indicating the error is another way to go about it.

Comment: I didn't think there was, but I wanted to give the community a chance to help. I'm definitely no expert when it comes to Python. I appreciate the great answer, which will be more than sufficient in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<exception> as e` and `raise <exception> from e`:

```py
def a():
    try:
        b()
    except IndexError:
        print('Caught the error in a!')
    print('Both chances are over now.')

def b():
    array = ["First", "Second"]

    try:
        print(array[2])
    except IndexError as e:
        raise IndexError('Caught the error in b!') from e
```